# More than one value in period one of those values within period inside period

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to find a way to find where there is more than one entry within a twelve hour time period for example 00:00:00 - 11:59:59 and one of the values is within a further time period within the twelve hour period (between 11:00:00 and 11:59:59 for example)

02:43:11
11:17:00

both times could also be between 11:00:00 and 11:59:59 if necessary.

There can be more than one entry in the twelve hour period but I am looking to find where there are at least two and at least one needs to be in the 11:00:00 - 11:59:59 band.

Hope this is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT [entry_id]
FROM [my_table]
GROUP BY [entry_id]
HAVING SUM
       (
            CASE WHEN [Date] >= '00:00:00' AND [Date] <= '11:59:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) >= 2
       AND
       SUM
       (
            CASE WHEN [Date] >= '11:00:00' AND [Date] <= '11:59:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ) >= 1
```